# log4j in a multi-module Maven project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, log4j

How do I implement log4j in a multi-module Maven project? Do I add a "log4j.properties" file to the src/main/resources directory of every submodule? If so, do I have to specify a different output file for each file appender? Or is there a way to have one overarching log4j.properties file for the whole project, without having a configuration nightmare. Which approach (many log4j.properties files versus one) is more common and better practice? Thanks for all feedback in advance.

Comment: The question is what you like to achieve? You can create a separate maven module which contains the log4j.properties in src/main/resources which will be used for other in production. Or are we talking about the unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you intend to deploy and run this project. For hierarchical multi-module projects, we generally included a log4j config file in the module with the `main` method that would launch the program.

For example, consider a simplified setup with projects `client` and `server` which both rely on `framework` for common classes (RMI interfaces, domain objects, etc). Client is run as a desktop application, has its own `main` entry point, and thus gets its own log4j.properties file under src/main/resources. So does the server module. Framework, however, does **not** get a properties file -- its logger calls will be handled by whichever loggers have been configured by its calling module.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this - I am running the project with jetty. How to configure log4j with jetty? I also want to be able to run unit tests without jetty, and still have it log. Or run the project with Tomcat and still have it log. It's (obviously) a webapp.

Comment: Later versions of log4j should detect the configuration file in your classpath, which it will be if you put it in the src/main/resources folder. It shouldn't require different configurations for Jetty. I usually prefer to not have logging in my JUnit tests -- you can override the default config with a testing-specific one by putting a different properties file in src/test/resources.